# "escaping" variable before passing it to template in Django

Tags: django-templates, escaping

I need to pass HTML code to `messages` and am doing so using templates.

In order to get the HTML to work, I mark the message as safe in my template:

> {{ message|safe }}

However, this leaves me open to attack as I'm displaying user generated content in the message. For example:

> messages.success(request, "Awesome!
>   \"%s\" is now active." % user_toy)

If user_toy is generated by the user, HTML will go unescaped. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using `escape` from `django.utils.html`:

> from django.utils.html import escape
>
> messages.success(request, "Awesome!
>   \"%s\" is now active." %
>   escape(user_toy))